# MySql update order/rank colum but allow for duplicate ranks

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have a table with game scores for each team like this:

```
id   game_id   game_rank   score   team_id
-------------------------------------------
5    1         0           15      1
4    1         0           25      2
1    1         0           40      3
3    1         0           40      4
2    1         0           55      5
7    2         0           0       1
6    2         0           0       2
```

I want to automatically sort the teams by score and assign them a game rank (first place, second place...) according to those scores. I would like to allow for ties based on duplicate scores, and only increment the rank if the score is different.

This is my desired result.

```
id   game_id   game_rank   score   team_id
-------------------------------------------
5    1         1           15      1
4    1         2           25      2
1    1         3           40      3
3    1         3           40      4
2    1         4           55      5
7    2         0           0       1
6    2         0           0       2
```

I have the following query so far, but it does not allow for duplicate game ranks.

```
SET @lastscore = 0;
SET @ordering = 0;

UPDATE game_scores SET game_rank = (@ordering := @ordering + 1)
WHERE game_id = 1
ORDER BY score;
```

Can anyone help me handle the duplicate scores?

Comment: A more typical ranking system would place your fourth place as fifth and skip fourth since there is a tie in third. Might complicate your algorithm a little.

Comment: Any reason why this was voted down besides someone having a bug up their ASCII?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SET @lastscore = 0;
SET @ordering = 0;

    UPDATE game_scores 
      SET
        game_rank = IF(score = @lastscore, @lastscore, (@ordering := @ordering + 1))
        , score = (@lastscore := score)
    WHERE game_id = 1
    ORDER BY score;
```

**You also can do it in one query:**

```
UPDATE game_scores 
  CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @lastscore:=0, @ordering:=0) AS parameter
  SET
    game_rank = IF(score = @lastscore, @lastscore, (@ordering := @ordering + 1))
    , score = (@lastscore := score)
WHERE game_id = 1
ORDER BY score;
```

Comment: This is correct except a typo in the if sending the `@lastscore` to the `game_rank` instead of just `@ordering`. I edited my question to show what I mean.

Comment: what a smart way to set the user variable in UPDATE! I has been looking for this for several days

Comment: My mysql doesnt like the CROSS JOIN - `Unrecognized keyword. (near "CROSS" at position 31)`

Answer (score 0):

you should check the condition every time when score are not same with previous score then @ordering increase by 1 other wise @ordering same as current @ordering

```
SET @lastscore := 0;
SET @ordering := 0;

UPDATE game_scores SET 
IF(@lastscore = score, @ordering, @ordering := @ordering + 1),
game_rank = @ordering,
@lastscore := score
WHERE game_id = 1
ORDER BY score;
```

Comment: This was giving me errors for some reason `Unrecognized keyword. (near "IF" at position 45)`